# Social networks in an Delphi win32 application

Tags: delphi, winapi, social-networking

I want to create some kind “social” connection/interaction in an application that I am creating.

The application is for a restrict group of professionals, that would benefits for social connection/interaction with each other.

So now I don’t know what to do. Do something new, integrate with an existing one ?

I am open for ideas.

---- UPDATE ----

Some basic features should be:

•Private Messages

•Blog functionality

•Publications

•A user profile, with basic info

•Friends list

•Pools

Open source product, if possible.

Platform. For now yes win32 application. Later if the concept catch on we can go web. Be this is only an extra feature of a big application, not the main feature.

Comment: What exactly is your programming question? Are you asking how to program something?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite vague but I try to give you some pointers.

First you need to define what functionality you want in your application. You want a social network site for professionals so we can rule out the fluffy bits. But there are other aspects of a social network site that you maybe want to include:

- Real time chat (one on one or multi, and do you want to include voice and view)
- Private Messages (like email)
- Discussions (like a discussion forum)
- Blog functionality
- Publications
- A user profile, and what do you want to include.
- Do we need to maintain a friends list?
- And special purpose groups.

Then you need to decide if you are going to buy, take or make the software. Maybe you can adapt some open source product.

Then you need to decide on a platform. You have tagged this question delphi win32. But why not use a web based concept.

If you have more concrete problems, we are glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your requirements– you need a web based application

Use something like [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) it can do all the basic features you require
And you will not have to write a single line of code.

It uses MySql as it’s database – and has hundreds of different plug-ins